# nuxt 3 vue router data fetching and caching

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs3

I'm really confused and stuck.

Here is what I think I understand so far in my code below.

1. PART A: before mounting it's gonna start trying to get datas on the serverside already.
2. PART B: when mounted on client, wait for datas to be ready, and do masorny layout.
3. PART C: since it is a component where I list all the datas, when the query changes, it will refresh the data with newly given queries.

Here is what I'm stuck at.

1. If I go to other page, for example detail page, 
   and comes back to list page by back and forward button, 
   no additional data fetching is sent, and scrollBehavior works as expected.
2. but when I change queries for other results, 
   then want to do back button to previous query result, 
   as written clearly in PART C, it fetches data again, saved scroll position is gone.

I'm not getting why in (1) nuxt automatically doesn't fetch same data 
and how I should save fetch request and resotre scroll in (2) where I'm navigating within a single component.

```js
const { data: designs, pending, refresh } = useLazyAsyncData('design', 
  () => fetchDesigns()
) // PART A

onMounted(async () => {
  await until(pending).toBe(false).finally(() => masonry()) // PART B

  watch(() => useRoute().query, async () => { 
    window.scrollTo({ top: 0 })
    page.value = 1
    await refresh()
    await until(pending).toBe(false).finally(() => {
      masonry()
    })
  }) // PART C
}
```